# (Ubuntu 15.10) startx crashes with no error, then system hangs

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, 15.10

After updating to Ubuntu 15.10, I've been hit with problem after problem. However, this most recent one has to be the worst yet.

Upon startup, my computer runs in low-graphics mode. Attempting to run in default settings kicks me to a tty. Viewing the xorg log tells me that lightdm is generating a broken xorg.conf, so the first thing I do is open a tty and type `sudo nvidia-xconfig`. Restarting lightdm just regenerates the broken config, so I don't bother with that. But when I try to run `sudo startx`, it blackscreens, which I expect, but then kicks me back to the tty, which shows no error message, just `waiting for X server to shut down (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.` From there, the system hangs, and I can't type in anything; the only button that actually does something is the power button.

I have a GeForce 745m card, on an Asus Q550L laptop.

I've tried following this this thread, even mixing and matching solutions to no avail: [How to solve black screen problem after installing nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 15.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691946/how-to-solve-black-screen-problem-after-installing-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-15-1?rq=1)

Any ideas?

(edit) I've updated my kernel to 4.3.0, based on a different error I was getting previously. After purging and reinstalling nvidia-355, I noticed that dkms was telling me that this kernel is not supported. I would assume this is linked, but it was a solution to another, similar problem, so I don't know what I should do with it...

...And now `nvidia-xconfig` is gone, so I can't even use that to regenerate xorg.conf properly. I'm going to attempt installing `nvidia-current` over `nvidia-355`, then reinstall the latter. That should bring back `nvidia-xconfig`. (EDIT: It did.)

Comment: How about hardware information, like cards/graphics?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the same issue if you remove the nvidia drivers and use the Nouveau drivers instead?

Here is what worked for me:
Start a root sheel (select advanced Ubuntu)

`mount -o remount,rw /`

`apt-get purge nvidia*`

`reboot`

`sudo apt-get purge xorg lightdm`

Autoremove whatever left

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

Install lightdm and xorg

`sudo apt-get install xorg lightdm`

Comment: For some reason, my computer won't allow me to get to the GRUB menu. I'll try those (except for the first, of course) in a tty using sudo.

Comment: No dice. Reinstalling the nvidia drivers.