# Cannot Login when second monitor is connected if nvidia card is active

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, login, multiple-monitors

I have a Dell Inspiron laptop which have an nvidia and an intel screen cards. Before I upgraded my Ubuntu to 15.10, there was no problem. Today I've upgraded the OS. Now, I cannot login if my external monitor is plugged to my laptop. I enter my username & password and press enter, it shows a black screen for a moment and it shows the login screen again. If I unplug the external monitor, it logins successfully. After it logins, I can plug and use the external monitor however if I logout & login it again does not login, same thing.

I switched from nvidia card to intel card and it works perfectly. Can I not use nvidia card anymore?

I removed nvidia drivers and installed nvidia-355 drivers (from this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/692631/206689) but it has the same problem. Currently I'm able to use only intel card.