# Unable to boot from Ubuntu live USB on ASUS laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, live-usb

I recently bought a ASUS K501UX laptop with Windows 10 pre-installed.
I want to install Ubuntu in a dual boot with Windows 10.

I tried:

- Advanced: Set Fast BIOS mode to disabled
- Boot: Set Secure Boot to Disabled
- Boot: Boot device priority -> set USB-HDD at the top
- I also turned off fast boot option under Control Panel under Windows 10.

After restarting with my bootable USB, the computer freezes. This is
the last screen photo I took.

[image]

Do you have any ideas on what I need to do to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10?

Comment: Try using the answer from this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

hmm according to the screenshot it seems to be a nouveau error.

nouveau is the open-source nvidia driver and may not support your card. if it's 900M-series.

Can you access the GRUB menu?, if so then try putting

```
nomodeset
```

as [kernel parameter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076) in place of quiet splash, it should boot you into desktop, but you will always have to put it on boot, unless you [install the proper drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691946/how-to-solve-black-screen-problem-after-installing-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-15-1/692271#692271).

Also, do you have by any chance a Skylake processor?, then you at least 15.10 is recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, putting nomodeset I was able to try ubuntu (it did not recognize the wireless card though).

Comment: well, then you need an ethernet adapter to connect to the internet, install Ubuntu, install the appropriate drivers for your nvidia-card, then go to Ubuntu-Software-Center->Edit->Software and Sources->Additional Drivers and it may probably have a proprietary driver for your wireless card (ignore the ones for nvidia) see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/235279/my-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-at-all-how-to-troubleshoot